# Infopath source file is deleted, How to recover it from published form library in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have form library which was created by publish a custom Infopath Form over SharePoint Online, it had various view and, rules and form load rules.

But now the source file is deleted by mistake, and I need to make some publish the same form into another sites/libraries with some amendments.

Is there any way I can get that form back from this running form library !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to library settings --> advanced. Look for the entry for the template, and click to edit the template. It should open in InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted the infopath form, there is no way to recover it.

I am afraid that you need to create the infopath from scratch.